# How do you disable SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT for some views in Django?

Tags: python, django, web-services, ssl, https

I have a site where I want to set `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True` for most views, but there is one view that I need to disable SSL (for communication with a client program that doesn't support it).

I could create a whole new Django project for the view that doesn't require SSL, but there must be an easier way to manage that.

How can I selectively turn off the SSL redirect?

Comment: why not use `SECURE_REDIRECT_EXEMPT` ?

Comment: @RajaSimon That's what I was looking for! Thanks, I don't know how I missed that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Best way to `disable` SSL is to define `SECURE_REDIRECT_EXEMPT` in settings...